# Will a `fetch` call continue if the tab is closed?

Tags: javascript, browser, fetch-api

Browsers now offer the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), which you can make network requests from JavaScript like this:

```
const response = await fetch('http://example.com/movies.json');
const myJson = await response.json();
```

What happens if the user closes the tab between the call to `fetch` and the fulfilment of the promise? Will the browser drop the request? What if the call to `fetch` happens in the `unload` or `beforeunload` events?

I know [`sendBeacon`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon) is the API call that is meant for this purpose, but I am wondering if `sendBeacon` is obsolete now that we have `fetch`.

Comment: The standard says "forcibly close eventSource", when closing a document. [fetch instance](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/server-sent-events.html#concept-eventsource-forcibly-close) is an eventSource, and is aborted during the document [closing process](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsing-the-web.html#unload-a-document).

Comment: Note that you probably want the `visibilitychange` event, because `beforeunload` doesn't always fire, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event#usage_notes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the `keepalive` option of `fetch`:

> The `keepalive` option can be used to allow the request to outlive the page. Fetch with the `keepalive` flag is a replacement for the `Navigator.sendBeacon()` API.

Here is an example:

```
await fetch("/example", {keepalive: true});
```

Requests sent with `fetch` and the `keepalive` option get a high priority compared to requests sent with `navigator.sendBeacon`. The `fetch` API is also much more flexible and provides more options. Without `keepalive`, there is no guarantee that the request will be completed if the user closes the page.

#### References:

- [Reliably Send an HTTP Request as a User Leaves a Page](https://css-tricks.com/send-an-http-request-on-page-exit/) by Alex MacArthur
- [`fetch()` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch)

Comment: Note to self: With `keepalive`, it also continues even if the browser is closed.

Answer (score 0):

If the HTTP request has been sent when the JS environment that triggered it goes away, then it has been sent.

If it goes away before that, then the request won't be sent.

If the load event hasn't fired before the environment goes away, then the event handler will never be called. It doesn't exist any more.

> What if the call to fetch happens in the unload or beforeunload events?

Then, odds are, that the JS environment will go away before the request is sent.

> I know sendBeacon is the API call that is meant for this purpose

Yes

> but I am wondering if sendBeacon is obsolete now that we have fetch.

No

Comment: I'm more interested in whether the request is completed rather than whether the JS environment is still running. It seems from your answer that only `sendBeacon` can be used to send a request and ensure that the request is not aborted because a tab is closed.